# In Rails, how to display a name instead of id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm looking to do is have the url display something like: books/grapesofwrath

However right now it's simply books/32

In my controller I have the following:

```
def show
 @book = Book.find(params[:id])
 @header = true
 @metatoon = true
end
```

Everything works fine with this but I want the url to be using the book name. So I changed it to:

```
 def show
 @book = Book.find_by(book_name: params[:book_name])
 @header = true
 @metatoon = true
end
```

Cool. I think it's correct but I end up with the following error when loading a show page:

```
undefined method `book_image' for nil:NilClass
```

I feel like I was wrong in how I change the params to search by book name. Is there something I should be doing in route?

Comment: use the gem that VAD has suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find useful [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. It's created exactly for those kind of stuff.

Comment: Only problem is I'm getting Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'books.slug' but it's closer

Comment: Need more details, there could be several possible reasons. But maybe it's just `book.slug` instead of `books.slug`?

Comment: I skipped a simple step. I just needed to run from console Book.find_each(&:save). Updated the table.